# How to push Json object to Json array using for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a html table where onclick dynamically rows added. I need to convert that row textbox values into JSON array.

Note: `Ajax` must be used because I need to save data to `sql server`.

Here is my attempt.

```js
$(function() {
  $("[id*=btnSave]").click(function() {
    $("[id*=data_table] tbody").each(function() {
      var arr = [];
      var user = {};
      for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        user.DueDate = $(this).find('tr:eq(' + i + ') td:eq(0) input').val();
        user.DueAmount = $(this).find('tr:eq(' + i + ') td:eq(1) input').val();
        arr.push(user); // Json array has every json object value
        $.ajax({
          async: true,
          cache: false,
          type: "POST",
          url: "Default.aspx/Save",
          data: JSON.stringify(user),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {
            alert("Data added successfully.");
            alert(JSON.stringify(user)); //Json object value //Alert 2
            alert(JSON.stringify(arr)); //Json array value  //Alert 3
          }
        }); //End of ajax
        return false;
      } //End of for loop
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" id="data_table" width="50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30%">Due date</th>
      <th width="26%">Amount Due</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="30%">
        <input type="text" id="Text1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Due Date" runat="server" />
      </td>
      <td width="25%">
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="new_Amount_1" placeholder="0.00" autocomplete="off" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add row" id="btnAddRow" />
        <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I used `for loop` to get every dynamically added row values.
My output should be like this.
`Alert2` Json object format

```
{"DueDate":"17/09/2019","DueAmount":"100"}
```

`Alert3` Json array format

```
[{"DueDate":"17/09/2019","AmountDue":"100"},{"DueDate":"18/09/2019","AmountDue":"200"},{"DueDate":"19/09/2019","AmountDue":"300"}]
```

But in My output `Alert3` I am getting first object only

```
[{"DueDate":"17/09/2019","DueAmount":"100"}]
```

What I have done wrong? I think for loop is not correct. Please help me with that.

Comment: Try to use console.log() instead of alert()

Comment: console.log() also same output only I'm getting.@Casper

Comment: you are redeclaring array every iteration of the loop (inside of `$("[id*=data_table] tbody").each`), just move the `var arry=[]` outside of the loop and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Removed for loop(each function already used).
2. As @Krzysztof Krzeszewski said, variable arr declared outside each function.
3. As @Nidhin Joseph said, Ajax moved outside of each funtion.

Final working output.

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        var arr = new Array();
        $("#data_table tbody tr").each(function () {
            var user = {
                DueDate: $(this).find('td:eq(0) input').val(),
                DueAmount: $(this).find('td:eq(1) input').val()
            };
            arr.push(user);
        });

        console.log(arr);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/Save",
            data: JSON.stringify(arr),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Data added successfully.");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping this, you can directly use the [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) or [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) if you need a custom format

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
  $.ajax({
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/Save",
    data: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("Data added successfully.");
    }
  }); //End of ajax
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
  <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" id="data_table" width="50%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="30%">Due date</th>
        <th width="26%">Amount Due</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="30%">
          <input type="text" name="Text1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Due Date" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td width="25%">
          <input type="text" runat="server" name="new_Amount_1" placeholder="0.00" autocomplete="off" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="Add row" id="btnAddRow" />
          <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: But I need Ajax? To save data to sql server. @Nidhin

Comment: yep, you can use the serialized json to send to your server. And why would you call server each time you loop?

Comment: okay I don't know that serialized json can send data to server. I don't know how to use for loop in ajax that's why i use like that.

Comment: You are telling that your serialized json code is same like my ajax code?

Comment: what I am saying is, instead of looping to create your array, you can use the `serializeArray()` and then send that to server. I have updated the code to inlcude your ajax as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use .serialize() or .serializeArray() and these two functions only runs on a form tag.

In your code if you are adding tr tag each time that you press btnAddRow, your for loop is wrong:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
```

Replace with:

```
for (i = 0; i <= $(this).find('tr').length; i++)
```